# Overridding Method for 'OK" button

Tags: android

I've created a simple Activity class for an audio example. But the problem is the the audio file keeps running even if I leave the app. I just want to stop the ACTIVITY by pressing the 'OK/DONE" button in middle of any phone. Which method should I override in the activity class?

```
public class Audio extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_audio, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    int resId;
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
    resId = R.raw.up;
    break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
    resId = R.raw.down;
    break;

    default:
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
        }

    // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mp.start();

    // Indicate this key was handled
    return true;


}

}/// end class
```

Comment: accept answers for the other questions you asked

Comment: See this link.. It may helpful to you to resolve your query. 
[Check this link]


  [1]: http://nisha113a5.blogspot.in/2012/01/intercept-home-key-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle what you want in onPause() method. Or you can also implement 
onDestroy() method. When you press home button or when you close the application, it goes to onPause() and then onDestroy().

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // stop player here
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: actually you don't need to override a button, you can simply follow the activity life cycle when you want to stop the player when you close the application. see this link for life cycle.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: U r right but YET NOT WORKING.....m confused , I called the finish() method in onPause method, to no avail.

Comment: no need to finish your activity, all you need to do is to call mediaPlayer.stop() within onPause() method.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
    Toast.makeText(Audio.this, "You pressed the home button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    Audio.this.finish();                  
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

Comment: NO, ITS NOT WORKING....Pressing OK/HOME/BACK button doesnt stop the activity. Shouldnt I use the finish() method to stop activity ? the TOAST even doesnt show up.

Comment: Yes of course, you should use finish() , I was just trying to show, how to override the button you wanted.